# Python Server connect to multiple Clients

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, client

I have a short server script which sends a byte to a client informing it what game should be put on a screen. It works for one client but I want to send it to more, but can only send it to the client which connected last, and I cannot figure out why? Do I need to use multiple threads? The code I have is:

```
import socket
def gameChose():
        if nb=='Game1':
            conn.sendall(b'Game1')
        if nb=='Game2':
            conn.sendall(b'Game2')
        if nb=='Game3':
            conn.sendall(b'Game3')
HOST = ''                 
PORT = 50007              
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(2)
for x in range (0,2):
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print ('Connected by', addr)
while 1:
    nb = input('What kind of game would you like to play?')
    gameChose()
```

I have placed a for loop because I know how many clients are going to connect. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to keep `conn, addr` on list to have access to all users - `conn[0]`, `conn[1]`. Problem is `input` which stops program so it can be easier to run every user in own thread.

Comment: @furas Thank you for the quick answer, I am new to this but if I understand what you are saying correctly can I just write `conn[x], addr  = s.accept()` and then have all the users on a list?

Comment: it seems you have to learn how to use `list` in Python. First you have to create empty list `conn = []` and later you get `c, addr = s.accept()` and add to list `conn.append(c)`

Comment: BTW: there will be other problem - `accept()` waits for user connections so first client will to have to wait for all other user before it can't start game. So it is easier to run user in thread.